# how to write tags,meta data to a file with android java(when we right click on windows>properties)

Tags: java, android, file

I want to add a comment to a file(video,txt,etc...). right click on a file on windows the comment should appear.

```
File tempf= new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/picedittemp");
tempf.setcommentOrTittle("mycomment to file");
```

Comment: if anyone could tell me how to ask more questions would be good, in yahoo answers if we answer other peoples questions we can ask more questions, is that same way this site work?

Answer (score 0):

Not all files contain a comment field so there is no standard way of doing it. Each file type however will have a library which will allow you to modify its tags. An mp3 for example has the JAudioTagger library which allows you to set tags like this.

```
//No guarantee this will work (just an example)

 File track = new File("C:/path/to/song.mp3");

 AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(track);

 f.getTag().setField(FieldKey.COMMENT,"My Comment");
```